# Appium not working in UBUNTU

Tags: android, ubuntu, appium

Hi I am trying to set up the appium in Ubuntu but when I try to run the test the below error is coming.I have installed android sdk and set the path for ANDROID_HOME,TOOLS, PLATFORM_TOOLS...still the adb is not able to found it seems, please help.........................................................

>

```
 ``MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"browserName":"Chrome","p...
[Appium] Creating new AndroidDriver session
[Appium] Capabilities:
[Appium]   browserName: 'Chrome'
[Appium]   platformName: 'Android'
[Appium]   deviceName: 'sony'
[Appium]   platformVersion: '4.3'
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: ff57a14e-8a49-4a79-8669-7ead18af9cbe
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Getting Java version
[AndroidDriver] Java version is: 1.8.0_111
[AndroidDriver] We're going to run a Chrome-based session
[AndroidDriver] Chrome-type package and activity are com.android.chrome and com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main
[ADB] Checking whether adb is present
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Called deleteSession but bootstrap wasn't active
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forceStop' of undefined
    at AndroidDriver.deleteSession$ (lib/driver.js:354:19)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:108:47)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:119:28
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/$.microtask.js:19:5)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:419:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 423 ms - 182
```

Comment: can you try to run command adb devices in shell?

Comment: I got it working when I run as super user...... "sudo adb devices"

Answer (score 0):

You must run `appium-doctor` first for it to verify correct setup before launch of the tests.

More info: [Appium Doctor GitHub](https://github.com/appium/appium-doctor)

Comment: I got it working when I run as super user...... "sudo adb devices" and also start appium as super user